# Rationale for std::make_array common type

Tags: c++, c++17

[std::make_array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) uses the common type. However, my main problem with this is that it allows code to compile that would otherwise not compile:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T a, T b)
{
}

int main()
{
    auto arr = std::experimental::make_array(1, 3.0); // Compiles
    foo(1, 3.0); // a and b types must match
    std::array<int, 2> arr2{1, 3.0}; // narrowing conversion
}
```

This is not necessarily a bad thing. But I find it to be inconsistent. Note that due to how template argument deduction works, `std::make_array<int>` actually *disables* deduction (because you specified a type explicitly) so that does not solve the problem.

What is the rationale behind using common type here?

Answer (score 1):

> `std::make_array` uses the common type.

What *else* should it use to deduce the type of the elements of the to-be-created array?

The first element? If so, wouldn't it be very inconsistent to have ...

```
auto a = make_array(1, 3.0);
auto b = make_array(3.0, 1);
```

... a different type of array for those two?

Sure, one could SFINAE or `static_assert` that all types of the passed arguments to `std::make_array` are the same, but then you artificially restrict the use of that function *a lot*. Consider:

```
short x = 3;
auto c = make_array(x, 42); // Should this be a compiler error? I'd say no ...
```

You can go further and loosen the requirement of the types being the "same" to types that are (in some sense) compatible. But then, aren't you already more than halfway at the `std::common_type` ...?

The [(probably) official reasoning (N3824)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3824.htm) is that the intention is to provide both a "tuple-like" interface as well as an "array-like" interface. Where the former acts like `std::make_tuple` or `std::make_pair` and deduces some suitable (thus common) type, the later reflects raw array declarations like ...

int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

... which do *not deduce* the type of the elements but rather only the array length.

Comment: Well, OP suggests to _not_ deduce the type, preferring compilation failure over over-zealous deduction. Not an unreasonable preference IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but a possible solution for what you want.

You could solve it by implementing your own function helper. There are some tricks to enforce the strict narrowing conversion and not use a common type to deduce the elements' type. One could implement it by checking `std::is_same` for each argument:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_array(Args&&... args) -> std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)>
{
    static_assert((std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::decay_t<Args>>{} && ...), 
                  "arguments shall be of same type.");
    return {{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
}

int main()
{
    auto a = make_array<int>(1, 2, 3);

    // ↓ error: static_assert failed "arguments shall be of same type."
    //auto b = make_array<int>(1, 2, 3.f);
}
```

Values `1`, `2` and `3` are of type `int`, so the check passes. If you try to pass e.g. a value of type `float`, the static assertion won't let it compile, as `is_same<int, float>` resolves to false.

The only difference from `std::make_array` here is that you are required to provide the type of your elements (e.g. `make_array<int>`), so it won't deduce a common type based upon your arguments. Only size will be deduced from the arguments.

There can't be narrowing conversions here too, as the arguments' type all have to be exact the same as the one you provided.